# Есть ли тут связь?

Tags: подчинительная-связь

Не могу понять, почему предложения не связаны друг с другом с помощью личного местоимения и формы слов.

> (10)Но вот **я** **дунул** в неё, и она стала похожа на человеческую
> руку. (11)Что-то, чего ***я*** понять не мог, **дунуло** в глубину моего
> скомканного, измученного, искалеченного существа и выпрямило меня,
> мурашками оживающего тела пробежало там, где уже, казалось, не было
> чувствительности, заставило всего «хрустнуть» именно так, когда
> человек растёт, заставило также бодро проснуться и наполнило
> расширившуюся грудь, весь выросший организм свежестью и светом.

Связующие элементы выделила. Почему нет?